# Jquery $(document) on change returning null value for deselection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a Django form, and modifying an option list (in HTML) for one of the fields using $(document) on change for a different field in the form. When I select an option (multiple choice list, can select more than one - *not checkboxes*),

```
this.value
```

returns the correct value. However, when I deselect the option,

```
this.value
```

returns null. Why would this be the case? Is a value only returned when something is selected (as opposed to deselected)? If so, how can I get the value of the element that was deselected

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on("change", "#name2", function () {
    var url = #the url I'm using
    url += "&field=" + this.value + "&visible=1";
    value = this.value
    ...etc
```

Comment: Provide your code, please

Comment: Added code above

Comment: Also, I'm deselecting using command + click. The event handler does detect this when I deselect.

Comment: What do you mean by "deselect"?

Comment: Let's say I have a form field with 10 options, and another form field with 200 options. When I select one of the 10 options, I narrow down the choices to 20. If I select a different option, I get a different 15-20 etc. If I select the two choices I get 35-40 in the second field. Let's say I select/click two fields in the first form and want to remove one of them. I command+click to deselect, so only one field is highlighted and chosen.

Comment: @user7518095 Use `.selectedOptions` property instead of `.value` property

Comment: The value attribute of the select element returns the value of the first selected option.  Not only does deselecting an option not cause the select's value to be the value of that deselected option (why would it?) but reading the value in the onchange when a second option is selected won't necessarily return that newly selected option's value either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `val()` will return an array of values on a `<select multiple>` or null (depending on version):

```js
$(document).on('change', '#name2', function() {
  var val = $(this).val()
  console.log(val ? val : 'None selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="20" id="name2" multiple="">
<option value="1">Item 1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option>
<option value="4">Item 4</option>
<option value="5">Item 5</option>
<option value="6">Item 6</option>
<option value="7">Item 7</option>
<option value="8">Item 8</option>
<option value="9">Item 9</option>
<option value="10">Item 10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate `.selectedOptions` property of `<select>` element with `multiple` attribute set to get the `.value` of each selected `<option>` element at `change` event

```js
function getOptionValues(options) {
  return Array.from(options, function(el) {
    return el.value
  })
}

document.querySelector("select")
.onchange = function() {
  console.log(getOptionValues(this.selectedOptions))
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```